# Neo4j Query : Find the Average of values found after fetching the latest record (By Timestamp) for each row

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

"**Neo4j Query**"

Find the Average of values found after fetching the latest record (By Timestamp) for each row of a Java object(Node) which contains a List of another Java object(Node). Please have a look at below classes :

Class Train contains a List of Attributes object.

```
@Node
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Train {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String trainId;

  @Relationship(type = "HAS", direction = Relationship.Direction.OUTGOING)
  private List<Attributes> attributes;

  private String timestamp;
}
```

Attributes class is as below.

```
@Node
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Attributes {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String value;
}
```

The records in DB look like below :

```
{"id" : "123", "trainId": "train1","timestamp": "2022-05-27T10:10:10+00:00","attributes": [{"name":"fuelPercentLeft","value": "48"},{"name": "engineTemp","value": "56"}]},
**{"id" : "456", "trainId": "train1","timestamp": "2022-05-27T10:49:10+00:00","attributes": [{"name":"fuelPercentLeft","value": "39"},{"name": "engineTemp","value": "59"}]}**,

{"id" : "789", "trainId": "train2","timestamp": "2022-05-27T14:10:10+00:00","attributes": [{"name":"fuelPercentLeft","value": "88"},{"name": "engineTemp","value": "73"}]},
**{"id" : "983", "trainId": "train2","timestamp": "2022-05-27T16:22:10+00:00","attributes": [{"name":"fuelPercentLeft","value": "65"},{"name": "engineTemp","value": "71"}]}**,

{"id" : "553", "trainId": "train3","timestamp": "2022-05-27T23:10:10+00:00","attributes": [{"name":"fuelPercentLeft","value": "22"},{"name": "engineTemp","value": "44"}]},
**{"id" : "801", "trainId": "train3","timestamp": "2022-05-27T23:52:10+00:00","attributes": [{"name":"fuelPercentLeft","value": "20"},{"name": "engineTemp","value": "46"}]}**
```

**Note** : Database stores the historical data, that is trainId are repeated. Class Train contains the List of different attributes. The Bold records are the latest entries available in the database.

We need to write a Neo4j Cypher query which will fetch the latest record for every Distinct trainID. For these distinct trainIds we to find the average of fuelPercentLeft of all the fetched trains.
e.g. The output of above mentioned sample data should be 41.333. Because the the distinct records we found by applying latest Timestamp are as below :

```
{"id" : "456", "trainId": "train1","timestamp": "2022-05-27T10:49:10+00:00","attributes": [{**"name":"fuelPercentLeft","value": "39"**},{"name": "engineTemp","value": "59"}]},


{"id" : "983", "trainId": "train2","timestamp": "2022-05-27T16:22:10+00:00","attributes": [{**"name":"fuelPercentLeft","value": "65"**},{"name": "engineTemp","value": "71"}]},


{"id" : "801", "trainId": "train3","timestamp": "2022-05-27T23:52:10+00:00","attributes": [{**"name":"fuelPercentLeft","value": "20"**},{"name": "engineTemp","value": "46"}]}
```

Note the highlighted fields above. Average of fuelPercentLeft in all three trains is 41.333 (AVG = (39+65+20)/3).

Requirement : Query should fetch all the latest train records by timestamp available in DB and should return the AVERAGE value of their fuelPercentLeft. So the output should be 41.3333 in above case.

Below query is not working as expected :

```
MATCH (n:Train)-[:HAS]->(m:Attributes{name:'fuelPercentLeft'}) return n.trainId , MAX(n.timestamp) , m.value
```

Kindly help! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
MATCH (t:Train) 
WITH t.trainId AS trainid, MAX(t.timestamp) AS maxTimeStamp
MATCH (n:Train{trainId: trainid, timestamp: maxTimeStamp})-[:HAS]->(m:Attributes{name:'fuelPercentLeft'})
WITH count(n) AS trainCount, SUM(m.value) AS totalFuel
RETURN (toFloat(totalFuel) / trainCount) AS averageFuel
```

Here, we are finding the `maxTimeStamp`for each `trainId`, and then we fuel values for those trains, finally, we calculate the average.

Comment: HI @Charchit Kapoor. Thanks for the answer. But on the same query as you mentioned is it possible to RETURN multiple values and map it in java to an Object ?Something like below

`
**MATCH (t:Train) 
WITH t.trainId AS trainid, MAX(t.timestamp) AS maxTimeStamp
MATCH (n:Train{trainId: trainid, timestamp: maxTimeStamp})-[:HAS]->(m:Attributes{name:'fuelPercentLeft'})
where toInteger(m.value) > 50 AS good, toInteger(m.value) < 50 AS low
return count(toInteger(good)) AS goodValue, count(toInteger(low)) AS lowValue**
`
This is not working as expected due to 2 conditions in WHERE clause.

Comment: What do you need in the output precisely? Can you edit and update it in the question, your query in the comment seems erroneous

Comment: I just added another questions for my latest Query , as it is little different then requirement mentioned here. Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72824744/neo4j-query-apply-multiple-where-conditions-not-working

Comment: Cool. I will have a look